# Determining required vectors

Tags: algorithm, vector, rotation, linear-algebra

I have an object that is aligned with the direction that I want the forces acting on its body's axis to move it in the direction of my camera's +z axis . Since the body is aligned where its local axis are all aligned with the camera's axis, just adding a force to the body's +z axis, it moves in the direction that I want.

If I rotate the body, its axis are no longer aligned with the camera. But I still want the body to move forward in the camera's +z direction. How do I determine how to calculate the forces to the body's local rotated axis (X,Y,Z) to make it move in the camera's +z direction?

So I have a body that is rotated (30,135,-36) on the X,Y, and Z axis respectively. And I want to calculate the forces on each axis needed to move the body in the camera's +z direction. The coordinate system is left hand: X is right, Y is Up, Z is forward.

Any help or insight is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your first sentence is very hard to parse.  Perhaps you could lead off with some background about what the problem is you're trying to solve, what sort of systems you are using, and so on.  Also, this question may not really be a programming question but perhaps a math one (in which case it would belong on one of the other StackExchange sites).

Comment: sorry about that... Essentially I am writing some code for a 3d game that allows an object located in front of the camera/viewport to be forced directly away from the camera (+z). So if the object is not rotated and has the same rotation angles as the camera, the force would only be applied to the body's +z axis. But if the body happens to be rotated, then I have to determine the forces on all three of the rotated axis to make it still move in the camera's +z direction.

Comment: Would you agree with me if I said that moving "directly away from the camera" is not the same as "in the +z direction w.r.t. the camera"?  The thing is that a camera is essentially a sensor at a point in space, so moving "directly away" from it is not exactly the same as moving along a line parallel to the lens centerline (unless the object itself is on the lens centerline).

Comment: yes i would agree with that since the camera can also be rotated... i was just trying to make the problem easier by assuming that +z is the same as moving away from the camera, but i guess i just made it more confusing...

Answer (score 0):

If your transformation are being performed with a matrix (which is most likely the case), then you can take the inverse of the matrix which results from the rotations, and then multiply the force vector by the inverse. Since the force vector is aligned with the z-axis, it should have the form (0,0,z) before the multiplication.

Alternatively, if you don't use matrices, then this should work as well:

Start with the force vector (0,0,z), you can then apply the *negative* of each rotation in *reverse* order. If I understand your question correctly, you rotated by +30 degrees around the X, then +135 degrees around Y, and finally -36 degrees around the Z. So to calculate the necessary force vector, start with the vector (0,0,z), rotate it by +36 degree around the Z axis, then -135 degrees around the Y, and lastly -30 degrees about X. This should give you the force vector relative to the object's local coordinate system.

Comment: hmmm... I think I should have mentioned that the force being applied is referenced by the axis. So the force is a Vec3 that assigns the forces to the axis, X Y & Z. So I need to know the forces for each of the individual local axis.

Comment: Following my method will give you a Vec3 of the form (x,y,z), where the individual components *are* the forces for the local axis